How is maxLength/minLength translated by go-gin
I have a simple schema object SerialNumber defined as:
SerialNumber:
      type: object
      description: |
            A serial number of an entity. This is a basic string but with length limitations. Hence a separate type to uniquely
            identify such entities.
      properties:
       serial:
        type: string
        minLength: 5
        maxLength: 128
      required: [serial]
        type: string
        minLength: 5
        maxLength: 128
      required: [serial]
```

I used the openapi-generator to translate this to goalng with go-gin and the generated object is:
type SerialNumber struct {

    Serial string `json:"serial"`
}

Wondering what happened to the maxLength and minLenght specification?  How do I know on the generated golang side what the maxLength/minLength are for a SerialNumber? I was expecting that the json tags would have the maxLength/minLength attributes.
What am I doing wrong?

The go-gin-server generator only supports x-go-custom-tag extensions, not minLength or maxLength.
For example JavaSpring or rust-server do.
If what go-gin-server provides is not sufficient you could customize the generator and provide your own templates.
